# Range set in function clears when returning to mainsub

Tags: vba, excel

In the following code i set 3 ranges equal to variables.  I have no problem with `rngNext` and `rngDays`, they assign the correct variable to the correct range- no worries.

Bizarely, rngLast does not write to the worksheet. More precisely (upon stepping into the code), I can see the value being written to the sheet on the line`rngLast.Value = LastBillDate` as would be expected, but then disappearing after the `End Function` line, when i return to the main sub.

I have never experienced this before, the only thing i can think of is that it's maybe to do with the variable losing its value after I return to the sub, but surely it's already written to the worksheet?

```
Function DaysRemaining(lngBillDate As Long, lngRow As Long)

Dim rngLast As Range, rngNext As Range, rngDays As Range
Dim NextBillDate As Date, LastBillDate As Date

Set rngLast = Worksheets("Data").Range("G" & lngRow)
Set rngNext = Worksheets("Data").Range("H" & lngRow)
Set rngDays = Worksheets("Data").Range("I" & lngRow)

If lngBillDate > Day(Date) Then
    NextBillDate = CDate(Format(lngBillDate, "00") & "/" &      Format(Month(Date), "00") & "/" & Year(Date))
    LastBillDate = DateAdd("m", -1, NextBillDate)

Else
    NextBillDate = CDate(Format(lngBillDate, "00") & "/" & Format(Month(Date) +     1, "00") & "/" & Year(Date))
    LastBillDate = DateAdd("m", -1, NextBillDate)
End If



rngNext.Value = NextBillDate
rngLast.Value = LastBillDate
rngDays.Value = rngNext.Value - Date
End Function
```

Help appreciated as always.

Comment: That is odd. What happens if you just hardcode in a value for `rngNext`? That might help make sure there's nothing wonky in that value that's causing it.

Comment: I get the same result hard coding both variables, unfortunately rngLast disappears at the same point.

Comment: Woops, as,756tgs says, this behavior is expected if it's a workbook function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you are using or want to use the DaysRemaing Procedure:

1. If you are using it in-sheet, i.e. you are calling =DaysRemaining(x,y) then after the function has executed values won't stay as you expect. Excel in-sheet functions are built to only output to the cell they are called from, you cannot right to ranges using rng.value outside of the function. A function you use in-sheet can have multiple inputs, but only one output. (This is an excel limit). If you want multiple outputs then you need to return a array result.
2. If you are using this though VBA, then your code works as expected (I tried implementing it successfully). You'll just as a matter of good housekeeping need to change it to a Public Sub DaysRemaining(...). You don't need a Function as per definition of a function you are not returning anything but only using a procedure to do some remote work on the sheet.

The following :

```
Public Sub DoDaysRemianing()
    DaysRemaining CLng(Date), 2
End Sub
```

Also works fine, but you are calling it through VBA.